# Comment XML - make it more readable

Tags: xml, comments

I have an XML file about 1000 lines long that has a lot of internal dependencies. Does anyone know of any tools that would possibly work with comments to help explain what this XML does?

Comment: XML supports a comment node (`<!-- -->`), or is there something else being sought? (Broken XML parsers/clients will sometimes barf on comment -- or extra white-space -- nodes though.)

Comment: After the code is commented, is there a way to get those comments into another file? or maybe show any dependencies?

Comment: You could use XSLT. It can select comment nodes. You could output plain text, or create some sort of documentation in HTML. With some XPath magic you might also find interdependencies between parts of your document. Could you supply an example document with comments? And a bit of explanation what sort of output you'd like to see from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something utilizing an XML reader and schema provider.

Comment: Any details as to what it is?